# Check if item exists in array React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to check if an item exists in my array `data` and if it does then prevent it from being added to the array.

The `handleCheck` function will return true if an items already exists in the array but I'm not sure how to then use this to prevent the item from being added to the array.

I have attempted to use it in the `handlePush` function  `this.handleCheck(item) == false ?` it should check if it's false and if so then push, if it returns true it should say it exists but at the moment this is not working as it will push to the array even if the item exists and it will never console.log 'exists`

How can I change my handlePush function to use handleCheck and prevent an item that already exists in the array to be added again?

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KpnhkEKCpjXU0XlNlVm

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import update from 'immutability-helper'

const Wrap = styled.div`
  height: auto;
  background: papayawhip;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
`

export default class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
    data: []
    }

    this.handlePush = this.handlePush.bind(this)
    this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this)
    this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this)
  }

  handlePush(item) {

    this.handleCheck(item) == false ?
    this.setState({
    data: update(this.state.data, {
      $push: [
        item
      ]
    })
    })

   : 'console.log('exists')
  }

   handleRemove(index) {
    this.setState({
    data: update(this.state.data, {
      $splice: [
        [index,1]
      ]
    })
    })
  }

handleCheck(val) {
 return this.state.data.some(item => val === item.name);
}

  render() {
    return(
    <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.handlePush({name: 'item2'})}>push</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handlePush({name: 'item3'})}>push item3</button>
        {this.state.data.length > 1 ? this.state.data.map(product => 
          <Wrap onClick={this.handleRemove}>{product.name}</Wrap>) : 'unable to map' } 
        {console.log(this.state.data)}
        {console.log(this.handleCheck('item2'))}
        {console.log(this.handleCheck('item3'))}
      </div>
    )

  }
}
```

Comment: if you don't specifically need to use an array you could create a hashmap using object properties which would ensure uniqueness

Comment: thanks I'll look into the possibility of using a hashmap

Comment: i wasn't trying to answer the question just suggest an alternative to help you out, if you end up using this approach you should leave an answer to your own question with what you did :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

it should be:

```
handleCheck(val) {
    return this.state.data.some(item => val.name === item.name);
}
```

because `val` here is an Object not a String.

Check this out:
https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kpo0Rk6Z8ysenWttr7q

Comment: To clarify: the `{console.log(this.handleCheck('item2'))}` is passing a string, but the  `<button onClick={() => this.handlePush({name: 'item2'})}>push</button>` is passing an object.

Comment: thanks this works and thanks for clarifying @DaveSalomon I can see where I was going wrong

Answer (score 38):

While searching for **Check value exists in an array in React**, I was landed in this page and would like to give a solution (apart from this question) for others who think there is any special case to check for a value in an array using React.

You can rightly use the default JavaScript method too. There is nothing special when it comes to React.

```
var arr = ["steve", "bob", "john"];

console.log(arr.indexOf("bob") > -1); //true
```

Thank you.

Comment: Genius... absolutely genius. Simplicity at its best. I tried all manner of methods but this simple one-liner... dude, thanks!

Comment: I tried using this in my react app to validate a form input. This works well in all cases except when I enter and then remove "bob" from my input field, the validation does not fail for the empty field. Using includes() on the array instance fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Genius , this helped me great !

Answer (score 22):

Use the `includes()` method on the array instance.

```js
console.log(['red', 'green'].includes('red'))
console.log(['red', 'green'].includes('blue'))
```